# Fade in and Fade Out Text in DIV - Remove Loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I have created a DIV with 3 different quotes fade in and fade out.

I am using below jQuery code for the same.

```
(function() {
var quotes = $(".changetxt");
var quoteIndex = -1;
function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
}
showNextQuote();
})();
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="toptext">
    <div class="changetxt">
        ”The simple act of paying positive attention to<br> 
        people has a great deal to do with productivity”
        <p>- Tom Peters</p>
    </div>

    <div class="changetxt">
        ”If you deprive yourself of outsourcing and your competitors<br> do not, you are putting yourself out of business”
        <p>- Lee Kuan Yew</p>
    </div>

    <div class="changetxt">
        ”Focus on being  PRODUCTIVE<br>
        instead of busy”
        <p>- Tim Ferris</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working perfect but I don't want to loop, There are 3 quotes, so as soon as it shows last (third) quote it should stop animation and no loop.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `quoteIndex` is in the third execution. If it is, then `return`

```
(function() {
    var quotes = $(".changetxt");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        if (quoteIndex == 2) {
            return;
        }
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(4000)
            .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
```

**Update**

To have the last quote stay, you can use a different approach in which you conditionally call `fadOut`

```
(function() {
    var quotes = $(".changetxt");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(4000);
        if(quoteIndex < 2){
            quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length).fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
        }
    }
    showNextQuote();
})();
```

Comment: This worked exactly only thing is after last quote appears, div becomes empty, i rather want last quote to stay.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of showNextQuote, instead of return set the quoteIndex back to zero.

function showNextQuote() {
        quoteIndex += 1;

```
    **if (quoteIndex === 3) quoteIndex = 0;**

    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
    .fadeIn(3000)
    .delay(4500)
    .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call the function after the third time, like so:

```
(function() {
    var quotes = $(".changetxt");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        quoteIndex += 1;

        if (quoteIndex === 3) return;

        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .delay(4000)
        .fadeOut(500, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();
}());
```

Comment: Loop Stops at empty div, i rather want last quote to stay, for your ref, I paste HTML in question